# Browser hangs and crashes when using a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am executing two queries and evaluating the following conditions for each record:

- if `$production_query->row->0` is equal to `$jobcard_query->row->0`
- if `$production_query->row->1` is equal to `$jobcard_query->row->1`

When true, it should display the results of `$production_query`.

However, when using a `while` statement, the browser takes a long time to respond and crashes.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

My code:

```
$query = " SELECT job_card_num , die_qty,id FROM sample_jobcard ORDER BY id DESC”
$production_query = mysql_query($query,$connection1);
$query1 = "SELECT job_card_num , die_qty,id FROM com_jobcard ORDER BY id DESC ";
$jobcard_query = mysql_query($query1,$connection1);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($production_query))
{
    while(  $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($jobcard_query))
    {
        while (($row1[0] == $row[0]) && ($row1[1] == $row[1]))
        {
            echo $row[0] . $row[1]. $row[2]'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried JOIN?

Comment: It would probably be preferable to let the database do the work for you by accessing both tables in a single query. It would help to give the basic columns and desired output for people to be able to assist on that front.

Comment: Is your code actually using that "smart" quote, `”`?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the query to something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT sample_jobcard.job_card_num AS JOBCARDNUM, sample_jobcard.die_qty AS DIEQTY, sample_jobcard.id AS JID, com_jobcard.job_card_num, com_jobcard.die_qty, com_jobcard.id FROM sample_jobcard 
    join com_jobcard on sample_jobcard.job_card_num = com_jobcard.job_card_num AND sample_jobcard.die_qty = com_jobcard.die_qty ORDER BY sample_jobcard.id DESC";

$jobcard_query = mysql_query($query);

if($jobcard_query && mysql_num_rows($jobcard_query) > 0)
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($jobcard_query)) 
    {
        echo $row['JOBCARDNUM']." ".$row['DIEQTY']." ".$row['JID']."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you improve the answer to suggest why. The stack is not fond of code-only answers

Answer (score 0):

Replace `while`:

```
while (($row1[0] == $row[0]) && ($row1[1] == $row[1]))
{
    echo $row[0] . $row[1]. $row[2]'<br>';
}
```

With `if`:

```
if ($row1[0] == $row[0] && $row1[1] == $row[1])
{
    echo $row[0] . $row[1]. $row[2] . '<br>';
}
```

If your conditions ever evaluate as `true`, you have essentially written:

```
while(true) {
    // run forever
}
```

This will run forever (well, until maximum execution time).

You end up printing the same line over and over, producing a large document that your browser has difficulty handling, inducing a crash.